# How to handle ajax errors that were not handled by statusCode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, error-handling

I am making the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: successCallback,
    error: defaultFailureCallback,
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: statusCode
});
```

I am passing a few HTTP status codes in the `statusCode` parameter and the corresponding errors are handled by the respective functions. Now I want the `defaultFailureCallback` function to handle all the other error codes. How do I do this?

The signature of the error function in jQuery is: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`

The problem I am facing is that there is no way to access the actual `statusCode` parameter inside the `defaultFailureCallback` function. `jqXHR` does not seem to contain that information. (I can get the current status from `jqXHR.status`)

Comment: this link might help u : http://www.cupcakewithsprinkles.com/how-to-handle-http-redirects-with-jquery-and-django/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `this` variable which will contain the `statusCode` values too.

Answer (score 0):

`jqXHR` should have the property `status`, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Yes, but how do I know whether this was handled by some other function in statusCode? For example, I would like to do something like `if(xhr.statusCode[xhr.status] == undefined){doSomething}`

Comment: I see. Let's say you pass an object `statusCodes` to the ajax settings. You could do something like this: `if( typeof statusCodes[xhr.status] == 'undefined' ) // no handler function...`.